# Offline music player for iOS that can sort items by year (from MP3 tag)?

Tags: ios, music, media-player, iphone-app, mp3

I am having trouble finding a free iOS app that can simply load a bunch of MP3s (via 'File Sharing' from iTunes) and sort all tracks in the app by release year as taken from the MP3 tags.

I have tried:

- [VLC](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/vlc-for-mobile/id650377962) (no feature to sort by anything)
- [Apple Music](https://support.apple.com/ht204951) (can only sort songs or albums by 'Title' or 'Artist')
- [foobar2000](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/foobar2000/id1072807669) (despite a 'Sort albums by date' setting, it doesn't change from alphabetical order by default)

Answer (score 1):

The free [VOX](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vox-mp3-flac-music-player/id916215494) iOS app will do this.

You can sort by 'Artist then Year' in either 'Item View' or 'Track View'.